# Tailbounds for a rational function of the average of chi-squares

Tags: probability, bounds

Let $\chi^2(n)$ refer to a chi-square random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom. This variable has mean $n$ and there are various results about its fluctuation around its mean. In particular, there are very strong concentration results for $\frac1n\chi^2(n)$.

Let $X_n\sim\frac1n\chi^2(n).$ We construct a new variable from $X_n$. Let: $$Y:=X_n+\frac{X_n^2}{1+X_n}\,.$$

I would like to leverage the concentration results for $X_n$ to get concentration results for $Y$.
**Is this possible?**

To be more clear, I have tailbounds on $X_n$ of the form $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-1|>\varepsilon)=f(\varepsilon,n)\,,$$
and my intuition is that this should imply the same (or a similar) tailbound for $Y$.

**Note:** I have previously asked a similar question (now deleted), but asked without imposing a specific distribution on $X$. In fact I am interested in a slightly different distribution, but it is very similar and I hope this more simplified question can inspire a general solution.